# How to modify grunt to exclude all the bower_component readme and example files when running a dist command?

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I would like to run a grunt dist routine that excludes all extra files you get when using bower to install a package.

When I download a package using bower I get a bunch of readme files and example folders.

How would I do this?

I have tried modifying my grunt file to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to include only files you need in the `copy` task under file `Gruntfile.js`.

Remove the line `components/**/*`, add include files yourself, and your new `Gruntfile.js` should look something like this:

```
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.{ico,txt}',
        '.htaccess',
        'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
        'styles/fonts/*',
        'components/jquery/jquery.min.js',
        'components/lodash/lodash.js'
      ]
    }]
  }
},
```

Comment: I was trying to do this using require js fileExclusionRegExp, but i can move the copy files over to the above code. thanks!

Comment: using grunt-contrib-copy.

Comment: i hope this worked. grunt-contrib-copy is a great addition.

Comment: using fileExclusionRegExp: /^\.|\.((json)|(md)|(map)|(txt)|(sh))|scss|docs|examples|test|dist|Makefile|Rakefile|LICENSE|CNAME$/, // If the regexp matches, it means the file/directory will be excluded.: and grunt-contrib-clean to delete files/directories we couldn't catch with fileExclusionRegExp